# Does WCF use TCP and not UDP as one of it's transport mechanisms because UDP is not guaranteed?

Tags: wcf

Reading about WCP (woof, what a monster of a subject), and just into the earlier stages of what transports are available.  I note that TCP is available, but not UDP.  Is this because UDP is not always reliable...lossy with packets ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly think so. UDP is useful for streaming video or audio, not for reliable messaging.

Answer (score 2):

No official reason for that. Who knows may be we will have netUDPBinding in coming releases.
But most probably they gave priority to TCP as it is reliable.